# HTML Control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlcontrols

i am developing application and i have set some html control which are runat="server" on code behind i need to change there text,i made htmlcontrol[] array which contain those control now the problem which i am facing that it didn't showing my text property so that i can change there text dynamically
 my code is

```
HtmlControl[] htmlctrl = { ctl1,ctl2,ctl3,ctl4 };

        foreach (HtmlControl ctl in htmlctrl)
        {


        }
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your foreach loop?

Comment: Maxim:i am not getting the property of INNERTEXT OR INNERHTML so what i provide you i just need to set text from sql.

Comment: HTMLControl is base of all html controls and does not contain non-generic property like innerText. Use HtmlGenericControl and access propety InnerText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must type-cast html-control (which is textbox) to TextBox, in order to get Text property shown.

Comment: please typecast htmlcontrol to htmlgeneric control in such case, and then use INNERTEXT OR INNERHTML properties, eg: HtmlGenericControl gen = ((HtmlGenericControl)(ctl));